# How to calculate the volume of the solid described $x^2+ y^2+z^2 \le 9$ and $2 \le z \le \sqrt5$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume

How to calculate the volume of the solid described $x^2+ y^2+z^2 \le 9$ and $2 \le z \le \sqrt5$?

I try
$x=2r \cos \phi$,
$y=2r \sin \phi$,
$z=z$, but but probably not the way to go

Comment: Why not $\int\limits_2^\sqrt{5} \pi \left(\sqrt{9-z^2}\right)^2\, dz$ ?

Comment: so simple way??

Comment: Yup, since $x^2+y^2+z^2=9$ is a sphere, you are going to compute "a ball slice" volume. Since intersection of the ball with $z=c$ is a disc, it's required only it's area $\pi r^2$ to compute the volume. It's radius is $\sqrt{9-z^2}$, as the disc is $x^2+y^2\le 9-z^2$.

Answer (score 0):

$$V=\int_{-2}^{2}\int_{-\sqrt{4-y^2}}^{\sqrt{4-y^2}}\int_{\sqrt{5}}^{\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}}dzdxdy-\int_{-\sqrt{5}}^{\sqrt{5}}\int_{-\sqrt{5-y^2}}^{\sqrt{5-y^2}}\int_{2}^{\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}}dzdxdy$$